# Android - Lock screen operations through app

Tags: android

I am working as a freelancer. I just got a requirement for an app `Lock Screen Operation`.

Basically, when I click on a button through my app it should lock the screen and should run a `webservice` in background and it should also display images while the screen is lock.

And when I unlock the screen and if webservice is executed then I should go to url in default browser which I got as a webservice result.

So, my question is, Is above things are possible in android, if yes then upto what extent. Means how much freedom I have to customize things when screen is lock??

These things are not possible in `iPhone`

Comment: You can look up for Custom ProgressDialog. Begin it is Pre-Execute and dismiss it in Post-Execute.

Comment: You can lock the screen programatically, but I didn't understand the part where you said that it will run a webservice in the background that should display images while the screen is locked. If the screen is locked, you cannot see any images. Also, I am pretty sure you can go to a url once the screen was unlocked by using a service.

Comment: @DemVoids: Samsung Phone has a button to Unlock a device. But i won't unlock instantly..you should have to swipe.. so, when I press that button that time I can see the images..still screen is locked.. only mobile light is ON..

Comment: I understand now (sorry for the very late answer). If it is relevant, you will need to either: 1. Create a lock screen widget. 2. Create your own lock screen. 3. If Samsung has an SDK, they might have a solution for what you are trying to achieve. Good luck.